# Find Least Similar Vectors Python and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

if I have a list of arrays e.g;

```
[0,1,1,0,1,1,0]
[1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,1,0,1,1,1]
[1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,1,0,1,1,1]
[1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
```

and I want to find the *n* arrays the least like the others, what would be the best method?

e.g; I want *two* arrays that are the least similar to the group as a whole.

Comment: Can you define how you are measuring the similarity of one row to the group as a whole?

Comment: What's your *similarity metric*? Use that to calculate the pairwise similarity, then find the largest one.

Comment: @Mark That's kind of my question.  I could use cosine similarity and find an average of the whole and perhaps calculate distance from the average... but I feel like the results might actually be close to each other?  Just wasn't sure if this is a common enough problem that numpy might have a built in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need to make some methodology choices before you can actually implement a solution.

1. How do you define *most different*? You need to choose or define the distance measure you would like to use. The appropriate measure is really dependent on the problem you are trying to solve
2. How do you define the difference of a single array vs the group of arrays? For example, you could define a method whereby you leave one out, take the average of the rest, and then compute the distance between the array you left out vs the average of the rest. Alternatively, you could compute distance between all pairs of arrays in your group, and then choose the two whose average difference vs the rest is the largest.

Some ideas for (1):

- [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) which essentially just counts the number of entries that do not match between two arrays. Since your example given is binary it may be appropriate
- [The L2 norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) of the difference of the vectors (essentially just the sum of squares of the difference between each entry). Probably the most popular, at least in some domains. Note that it is more sensitive to outliers, which you may or may not want. You can also compute the L1 norm instead, which is just the sum of the absolute difference, and in the binary case will match the Hamming distance.
- Many many more. Try searching distance measures for arrays, or clustering distance measures and so on. It really comes down to the interpretation of your data.

Once you have chosen desired methodology for (1) and (2), the implementation should not be too difficult.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm giving you the check mark because, as you'd stated to some degree, there are several ways to skin this cat.  Wasn't sure if this was common enough of a problem where there is a standard solution, so I appreciate you laying out some potentials.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to be helpful. I also just had a though that you could approach it as an outlier detection problem, for which there is another set of established methods available. The difference is that generally in outlier detection it is not assumed a priori that there are any outliers, so not sure if would be useful to you.